# The callback function in RegisterWaitForInputIdle does not execute as expected

Tags: c++, winapi

I am trying to execute a callback function using RegisterWaitForInputIdle, but seems like there is an issue with the code, which does not let the callback execute and goes ahead, I have tried debugging step by step but sadly it does not execute.

Here is the code :

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>

#pragma comment (lib, "kernel32.lib")

VOID CALLBACK CallbackFunc(PVOID lpParameter, BOOLEAN TimerOrWaitFired)
{
    std::cout << "Callback function called." << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    // Load kernel32.dll
    HMODULE hModule = LoadLibraryA("kernel32.dll");
    if (!hModule) {
        std::cerr << "Failed to load kernel32.dll." << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    // Get the RegisterWaitForInputIdle function
    auto RegisterWaitForInputIdleFunc = reinterpret_cast<BOOL(WINAPI*)(HANDLE, DWORD, WAITORTIMERCALLBACK, PVOID, ULONG, DWORD)>(GetProcAddress(hModule, "RegisterWaitForInputIdle"));
    if (!RegisterWaitForInputIdleFunc) {
        std::cerr << "Failed to get RegisterWaitForInputIdle function." << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    // Create a waitable timer
    HANDLE hTimer = CreateWaitableTimer(NULL, FALSE, NULL);
    if (!hTimer) {
        std::cerr << "Failed to create waitable timer." << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    // Set the timer to trigger after 5 seconds
    LARGE_INTEGER liDueTime;
    liDueTime.QuadPart = -200000000LL; // 5 seconds
    if (!SetWaitableTimer(hTimer, &liDueTime, 0, NULL, NULL, FALSE)) {
        std::cerr << "Failed to set waitable timer." << std::endl;
        CloseHandle(hTimer);
        return 1;
    }

    // Register the wait with RegisterWaitForInputIdle
    DWORD dwThreadId = GetCurrentThreadId();
    if (!RegisterWaitForInputIdleFunc(hTimer, dwThreadId, (WAITORTIMERCALLBACK)CallbackFunc, NULL, INFINITE, WT_EXECUTEDEFAULT)) {
        std::cerr << "Failed to register wait." << std::endl;
        CloseHandle(hTimer);
        return 1;
    }

    std::cout << "Wait registered." << std::endl;

    // Wait for the timer to trigger
    DWORD dwRet = WaitForSingleObject(hTimer, INFINITE);
    if (dwRet == WAIT_OBJECT_0) {
        std::cout << "Timer triggered." << std::endl;
    }
    else {
        std::cerr << "Wait failed with error: " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
    }

    CloseHandle(hTimer);
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Looking forward to solutions & advices.

Comment: Yeah, the callback program does not work even without casting too! Is there any reason fr the callback not being executed?

Comment: Having to cast a callback function is a sign of impending ill doom. If the callback function does not exactly fit that the registration function expects, the call back function will not be called correctly. `(WAITORTIMERCALLBACK)CallbackFunc` Casted the callback function. Remove the cast. If the program compiles without warning , you're safe. Otherwise, the program's broken.

Comment: Please expand on *sadly it does not execute.* What does not execute? The debugger? The program does not run at all? The timer does not behave as expected and wake the program back up? Describe the behaviour expected and show us the behaviour you see instead.

Comment: `RegisterWaitForInputIdle` looks to be an undocumented function. I feel your pain.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? If `RegisterWaitForInputIdle` checks the same condition as `WaitForInputIdle`, then that isn't useful outside of OLE programming.

Comment: Yeah, just removed the cast, and executed it and the wait is registered and the timer too, but not the callback function adding image here : https://imgur.com/ZZaf4Ny

Comment: @IInspectable I am trying to use the callback function as intended to pop up a simple message box

Comment: See [WaitForInputIdle should really be called WaitForProcessStartupComplete](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20100325-00/?p=14493).

Comment: Just build and run the x86 flavor of this program to see that you haven't guessed at the parameters correctly.

Answer (score 2):

`RegisterWaitforInputIdle()` is undocumented (where did you find its signature?), but as its name suggests, it is likely just an asynchronous form of `WaitForInputIdle()` (ie, by calling `WaitForInputIdle()` in a thread pool).

`WaitForInputIdle()` expects a `HANDLE` to a process, but you are giving `RegisterWaitforInputIdle()` a `HANDLE` to a timer instead.  So, that could easily explain why your callback is never being called, since there is no "idle process" being detected.

To wait on a timer in a thread pool, use the ([documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-registerwaitforsingleobject)) `RegisterWaitForSingleObject()` instead.

---

**UPDATE**: based on [ReactOS source code](https://doxygen.reactos.org/d9/dd7/dll_2win32_2kernel32_2client_2proc_8c_source.html), which appears to be mirroring the same API functionality as Windows (thanks @RbMm), `RegisterWaitForInputIdle()` actually has this signature:

```
VOID (WINAPI *)(WaitForInputIdleType lpfnRegisterWaitForInputIdle);
```

Where the signature of `WaitForInputIdleType` is:

```
DWORD (WINAPI *)(HANDLE hProcess, DWORD dwMilliseconds)
```

`RegisterWaitForInputIdle()` simply assigns an internal callback function of type `WaitForInputIdleType`, which `WinExec()` calls when it needs to wait for a newly-spawned process to enter an idle state.

```
WaitForInputIdleType UserWaitForInputIdleRoutine;

...

VOID
WINAPI
RegisterWaitForInputIdle(IN WaitForInputIdleType lpfnRegisterWaitForInputIdle)
{
    /* Write the global function pointer */
    UserWaitForInputIdleRoutine = lpfnRegisterWaitForInputIdle;
}

...

UINT
WINAPI
DECLSPEC_HOTPATCH
WinExec(LPCSTR lpCmdLine,
        UINT uCmdShow)
{
    STARTUPINFOA StartupInfo;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION  ProcessInformation;
    DWORD dosErr;
 
    RtlZeroMemory(&StartupInfo, sizeof(StartupInfo));
    StartupInfo.cb = sizeof(STARTUPINFOA);
    StartupInfo.wShowWindow = (WORD)uCmdShow;
    StartupInfo.dwFlags = 0;
 
    if (!CreateProcessA(NULL,
                        (PVOID)lpCmdLine,
                        NULL,
                        NULL,
                        FALSE,
                        0,
                        NULL,
                        NULL,
                        &StartupInfo,
                        &ProcessInformation))
    {
        dosErr = GetLastError();
        return dosErr < 32 ? dosErr : ERROR_BAD_FORMAT;
    }
 
    if (NULL != UserWaitForInputIdleRoutine)
    {
        UserWaitForInputIdleRoutine(ProcessInformation.hProcess,
                                           10000);
    }
 
    NtClose(ProcessInformation.hProcess);
    NtClose(ProcessInformation.hThread);
 
    return 33; /* Something bigger than 31 means success. */
}
```

For instance, this can be used to let `WinExec()` call `WaitForInputIdle()` itself, or to call a user-defined callback that has the same signature as `WaitForInputIdle()`.

Either way, this looks nothing at all like how you are trying to use `RegisterWaitForInputIdle()`.  Which goes back to my earlier question - where did you find your signature for `RegisterWaitForInputIdle()`, and why do you think it is the correct function for your task?  It does not appear to be, not even close.  So, you need to re-think what you are trying to accomplish.  You are using the wrong API for the wrong purpose.

Comment: it real implementation is https://github.com/mirror/reactos/blob/master/reactos/dll/win32/kernel32/client/proc.c#L1316 and it called from WinExec - https://github.com/mirror/reactos/blob/master/reactos/dll/win32/kernel32/client/proc.c#L4838 (also from LoadModule)

Comment: @RbMm That repo is not official Microsoft code. And besides, all that implementation is doing is assigning a callback function named `UserWaitForInputIdleRoutine` which `WinExec()` calls to wait for a spawned process to go idle. That implementation's signature of `RegisterWaitForInputIdle()` is nothing like what the OP's signature is using. So either way, the OP is not using `RegisterWaitForInputIdle()` correctly.

Comment: of course this not official Microsoft code, but i look first win11 implementation `RegisterWaitForInputIdle: mov UserWaitForInputIdleRoutine,rcx ; ret` so exatly the same. and called it primary only from `WinExec` - as in this code, only `UserWaitForInputIdleRoutine(ProcessInformation.hProcess, 30000);` - 30 sec instead 10

Comment: api itself and code from WinExec - https://i.imgur.com/lkL8uXb.png